# TokenError: Bad Request at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy when using google passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport-google-oauth

i keep getting this error in my console when trying to use passport authentication with google

```
TokenError: Bad Request
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy
```

this is my route

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: '58730156701-.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      clientSecret: 'tYjrSiieNi2l',
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback'
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    
    }
  )
);

router.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));
```

```
router.get(
  '/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const token = jwt.sign({ userId: req.user._id }, 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY', { expiresIn: '1h' });
      res.json({ token });
    } catch (err) {
    }
  }
);
```

my call backurl is using my frontend localhost, please why do i keep getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a problem in `googleStrategy` .Try saving and returning user to the callback function. You can do it with the help [findOrCreate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-findorcreate) package. check the docs for info on google strategy and authentication setup [passport-google-oauth](https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-google-oauth20/#:%7E:text=in%20your%20application.-,Configure%20Strategy,-The%20Google%20authentication)

```
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: '58730156701-.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      clientSecret: 'tYjrSiieNi2l',
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/google/callback'
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        //find the user if DB if not present then save the usernameField
        User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
            return done(err, user);
        });
    }
  )
);
```